# get encoded content from an div using soup

Tags: python, get, find, beautifulsoup, encode

I need the string SKU: E02165 witch is somehow encoded as

```
SKU:&nbsp;E02165&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

by some means, here is the full div strait from the web site

```
<div class="sku">SKU:&nbsp;E02165&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

I have tried

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
info = soup.find('div' , {'class':'sku'}).contents
```

as well all of the flowing

```
info = soup.findAll('div', { "class" : "sku"})
info = soup.find('div' , class='sku'}).contents
info = soup.find('div' , "class=" + 'sku'}).contents
info = soup.find('div' , {'class':'sku'}).text
info = soup.find('div' , {'class':'sku'}).contents
```

I have spent 2 hours strait on 2 lines of code if you can help me split the "sku:" from the number i think i could just use info = (info.split('sku: ')[1]) but if that dose nt work feel free to let me know.
thank you.

Comment: Can you use regular expressions?

Comment: No 
def handle_SKU(data):  #grabs SKU of item
 soup = BeautifulSoup("<div class='sku'>SKU:jjfjg</div>")#normaly data gose here
 info = soup.find('span', class='name').contents
 return(info) 
is what i am trying now but to no prevail
however this works...
def item_name(data):  #grabs name of item
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
 info = soup.find('span', itemprop='name').contents
 return(info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> div = '<div class="sku">SKU:&nbsp;E02165&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>'
>>> html = BeautifulSoup(div)
>>> div_sku = html.find('div', {'class': 'sku'})
>>> value = div_sku.get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').split('SKU:')[1]
>>> value
'E02165'
```

---

`get_text(strip=True)` will get the text part of a document or tag with whitespace from the beginning and end stripped.

`encode('ascii', 'ignore')` will ignore the unicode `u'\xa0'` in the text and therefore allows the `split()` to return accurate result.

Alternatively, you can also simply just do:

```
value =div_sku.get_text(strip=True).replace(u'\xa0', u'').split('SKU:')[1]
```

in which `replace(u'\xa0', u'')` will replace `u'\xa0'` with empty unicode string.

Comment: no it just locks up now when my program hits the code it stops no errors just stops responding I am using BS 4, apache 2, and python 2.7, windows 7 ualt... and i import the flowing                import cgi, cgitb, fileinput, Cookie, os, datetime, sys, urllib2, urllib
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: Wait it works IF i run it with out of the rest of my program if you want to see it with all the file heres a zip [link](http://98.154.16.253/stuff_junk/html%20strip.zip) Thank you for you time.

Comment: @RexFenderBaird Your code runs fine for me: `→ python scaner.py 
Content-type: text/html

[u'Glass Lens Screen with Tools Kit Set for iPhone 4 Black']
[u'LCD Touch Screen Replacement Assembly with Bezel Frame for iPhone 4 GSM Version Dark Blue']
info:  Thumb load,  URL list in`

Comment: @RexFenderBaird The only thing is you probably should have printed `handle_SKU(page)` instead of `item_SKU()`, for me it returns `u'BD005006'`.

Comment: WOW I cant believe i did not notice that! maybe I just needed sleep @Kay Zhu